# What is my NIC ID?

Tags: windows, nic

I need to get my NIC ID for a temporarily software license to be generated for me. How should I find my NIC ID?

I have found contradictory information on the web. Some suggested that I run `getmac.exe`:

```
C:\Windows\System32>getmac.exe

Physical Address    Transport Name
=================== ==========================================================
D4-BE-D9-1C-4F-C7   \Device\Tcpip_{7E28ABA4-55A5-4ECC-9B9A-8A440CDB9B95}
24-77-03-3E-B2-9C   Media disconnected
7C-E9-D3-FE-40-41   Media disconnected
24-77-03-3E-B2-9D   Media disconnected
```

From that, I assume my NIC ID is `{7E28ABA4-55A5-4ECC-9B9A-8A440CDB9B95}`. But then others have suggested to go to `Device Manager -> Network adapters -> [my NIC] -> Details` but I get many IDs in the same format as above, not just one:

[image]

Comment: no the nic id is more then likely the mac address.

Comment: So is `D4-BE-D9-1C-4F-C7` my MAC address?

Comment: In this case yes.

Comment: Also since you're running Windows one easy way to see the MAC address is to run ipconfig /all from the command prompt. It'll be listed in there as "Physical Address".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They probably mean your MAC address.  (The hexidecimal string under the `Physical Address` column of `getmac`. - Either `D4-BE-D9-1C-4F-C7`, `24-77-03-3E-B2-9C`, `7C-E9-D3-FE-40-41`, or `24-77-03-3E-B2-9D`, depending on which is your NIC/the Network interface this license will be run against.  Most likely `D4-BE-D9-1C-4F-C7`.)

Certainty will require asking whomever it is generating the license.  So ask, and while you're at it, tell them they're asshats for having that kind of licensing in the first place, in addition to not clearly specifying what identifier they require, precisely.

Comment: +1 for them being asshats, lol.

Answer (score 5):

These sorts of software licenses generally tie themselves to the MAC address of an Ethernet adapter in the server on which they're to be run. Which is annoying as hell when the NIC breaks and has to be replaced... So the NIC ID they're asking for is almost certainly the MAC address.

---

An [OUI search](http://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html) gives really interesting results for those MAC addresses:

```
24:77:03 Intel Corporate
7C:E9:D3 Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.
D4:BE:D9 Dell Inc
```

Just what on earth do you have in that server?

---

Anyway, to figure it out for sure, run `ipconfig /all` and scroll through the output until you find the entry matching your current IP address. A running example from my workstation:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 6C-62-6D-D1-DF-AD
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:db8:1600:80bf:4c09:a0d:9c35:30b3(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4c09:a0d:9c35:30b3%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.25.49.119(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, December 4, 2012 9:20:23 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, December 5, 2012 8:43:48 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::56e6:fcff:fef4:66f1%12
                                       172.25.49.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.25.49.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.25.49.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

You can see here that the IPv4 address is `172.25.49.1`, the IPv6 address is `2001:db8:1600:80bf:4c09:a0d:9c35:30b3` and the MAC address is `6C-62-6D-D1-DF-AD`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Intel PSG who specifically request customers provide their NIC ID to license our software. If you're here because someone at Intel asked you, here's exactly what we mean from the other side:

> **Network Interface Card ID:** NIC ID refers to the Network Interface Card
> ID that uniquely identifies your workstation within your network. You
> can find the NIC ID for your network card by typing `ipconfig /all` at a
> command prompt. You NIC ID is the number on the physical address line,
> minus the dashes.
>
> For example: 00C04FA392EF.
>
> Server IDs: Your server host ID is an 8- to 12-digit hexadecimal
> number. This number identifies the Unix*, Windows*, and/or Linux*
> workstation servers that the Intel® Quartus® development software or
> MAX+PLUS® II software licenses. Networked (or floating node) licensing
> requires a NIC number or server host ID. When obtaining a license file
> for network licensing, you should use the host ID from the Unix,
> Windows, or Linux workstation that will issue the Intel Quartus
> development software or MAX+PLUS II software licenses to distributed
> users over a network. If you do not know your primary server host ID,
> contact your server systems administrator.